# Is there any way to get system configuration value as true false in layout file(which is exists inside ui_component) array item in magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, uicomponent, configuration

I just wantend to get system configuration value inside the layout file which is exists in ui_component folder, in below code I just wantend to get system configuration value as true/false in the is_collection item.

```
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
   </argument>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this all step by step it will usefull you.

1.Define system configuration
In your module's **etc/adminhtml/system.xml** file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="mysection" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>My Section</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="is_collection" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Collection</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

2. Create a layout file
   **Vendor_Module/view/adminhtml/layout/path/to/your_layout.xml**

3.Create a UI component XML file

**Vendor_Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_ui_component_name.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/ui_component.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">${config path="mysection/general/is_collection"}</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- Your UI component code here -->
</form>
```

In the above code, **${config path="mysection/general/is_collection"}** retrieves the system configuration value with the specified path.

That's it! Now, the is_collection item in your UI component will have the value of the system configuration field defined in your module's **system.xml** file.

I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: I had tried that but it was giving this type of error 

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)

Comment: To resolve this issue, ensure that you're providing the correct boolean value for the configuration option in question..   1.Check the configuration file where you're defining the options.   2.ook for any boolean options or flags that might be causing the issue   3.Verify that you're providing a valid boolean value, such as **true** or  **false** and not an array or string.   If you're unsure which specific option is causing the problem, you can review your code or configuration files for any recent changes related to Next.js configuration.    Try this.....

Comment: I have used your code for system.xml and layout just for testing purpose but it is giving the same error .

Comment: sure.....! what error display?

Comment: it is giving this error (1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)) when i passed this ${config path="mysection/general/is_collection"} when i pass only true / false over there then it is working properly but when try to get system configuration as tru false then it is giving the error

Comment: Based on the error message you provided, it seems that you are passing the value **${config path="mysection/general/is_collection"}** to a function or code that expects a boolean value. However, this value is not a valid boolean value, which is why you are getting the error...  try this code {$isCollection = filter_var($config->getValue('mysection/general/is_collection'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);

// Now you can use the $isCollection variable, which will contain a boolean value
// Pass $isCollection to the function or code that expects a boolean} try this method